# Windows XP firewall blocks open connection made using C# socket

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-firewall-api

I make a client-server connection using C# sockets and while the connection is established in the client side I activate the firewall using the firewall api, after that, for some reason the client application becomes unable to send any data to the server and the two parts still connected. Is like the activation of the firewall blocks the connection. Why is this happening?
If more information is needed please just ask.

Comment: *Is like the activation of the firewall blocks the connection.* wat

Comment: @norkitt: *Is like the activation of the firewall blocks the connection* actually = It is just like the activation of the firewall blocks the connection, correct?

Comment: yes but why is this happening? Is there any way to activate the firewall while the connection is up but preventing the firewall blocks that connection?

Comment: @nor Will's point is that your question leaves a lot to be desired. Like clarity and proper grammar. Editing it to eliminate these problems will probably get you some useful answers. Check out the [FAQ] for some pointers.

Comment: I am guessing you bring the firewall down, then connect, then bring the firewall back up?  If so, the data you are seeing is expected.  You would need to add an exception to the firewall rules to allow your application network access.

Comment: I would assume the firewall will disrupt connections when coming back online. Can you reconnect after the firewall is back up?

Answer (score 0):

HEY you must go to the firewall's options and set the name of the applications that it doesn't have to block, or if you're creating a maliciuos thing you can do this though dos command line using NETSH.exe (look for netsh parameters on internet).
if the problem isn't solved, please post the code and I'll correct it.